# Google Drive API - Resumable uploads - Range header missing

Tags: google-drive-api

Under some circumstances the Range header is missing in the response to a resumable upload status request:

Request:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=<redacted> HTTP/1.1
<redacted>
Content-Range: bytes */5226496
Content-Length: 0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
<redacted>
Content-Length: 0
```

If this is by design, maybe it should be mentioned in the [Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads).

Comment: Under what circumstances exactly does this (the Range header missing in response to a status request) occur? Is it consistently reproducible? Does it only happen for certain files?

Comment: I can reproduce it consistently. It happens with mime-type application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not include the Range Header if Cloud Storage has not received any bytes yet.